# neural network recommendation can't get it to run

Tags: python, github, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

i know this will be quite a dumb question to ask since i should research more into it (which i did) but i got stuck after more than 5 hours and thinking that it will be a waste of time if i just keep going at it without a hint/clue to move on.

I was trying to run this project (https://github.com/mesuvash/NNRec) to actually see how the results will be like using the given training data, but i can't seem to get it running i already did the installation and most of my dependencies is there, but i can't do the "PYTHONPATH= python learner.py -c " step which after trouble shooting i think it read the utils folder in NNrec but doesn't read the blocks in nn folder which i really don't know how to even fix this

i'm using a windows 10 with cmder and i have 2.7 and 3.6 python installed in my laptop

Answer (score 1):

The Line 'PYTHONPATH= python learner.py -c ' is not intended to be a single command, I guess it's a typo, you have to run

`PYTHONPATH=<NNRec_PATH>` first to set the working directory and then

`python learner.py -c <CONF_PATH>` to actually run the learning Task

this is just a guess reading through the README of this particular project, I haven't tried this out.

---

**Generally**

I would recommend you some articles and tutorials on sites like [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/), [datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/), [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) to start.

I found [this one](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/convolutional-neural-networks-python) quite helpful as it provides you with everything needed to take off. You will set up the Environment and get your first classificator up and running, which gives you an immediate feeling of success in a couple of hours (I needed approximately 4 hours for this one).

(Btw.: I also would recommend a Linux dev box and NVIDIA GPU Hardware, not because it wouldn't work without it. In tutorials 95% of the time you will find Shell commands and typical Linux tools, therefore it is better documented and proved. And even it is not that easy to get NVIDIA CUDA and cuDNN up and running on an ubuntu box, it will give you less waiting time during training at factors between 10 and 100 which is extremely handy if you want to adapt your models)

Nevertheless, you should also consider taking courses and reading literature about the theoretical background ([this is a blog about it which I like very much](https://machinelearningmastery.com/blog/)) so that you are able to understand which type of Network/model is able to solve which kind of problem. The main question in machine learning is not to get an model up and running. There is plenty of Tools to basically fully automate this. Knowledge is needed to choose the right model and parameters and therefore adapt it to a specific Problem category.

Answer (score 0):

for trying out basic CNNs, I'd recommend keras & tensorflow. some pyimage (https://www.pyimagesearch.com) tutorials explain how to install and run some basic neural networks. HTH